# How to perform "like" query with full text search in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, scala, solr, full-text-search

I know that mongo does not support **$regex or like operation** with **full text search** at the moment.It only matches the text or the phrase.But I need to perform like query search on indexed fields.So, I need help regarding the choice of multiple search frameworks or any other work around to solve this issue.

I have nested document structure. For eg:

```
{
"name": "John",
"phones": [{
    "phone_number": "1234",
    "is_primary": true
}, {
    "phone_number": "5678",
    "is_primary": false
}]
}
```

I have tried using **Apache Solr** but I found that it does not provide good support for nested documents. It flattens the structure and indexes the fields but when I tried to perform like query as I have discussed above, it did not work.

I am using **scala, play and mongodb**.It is not feasilbe for me to change the nested document structure now. What are the suitable search platforms that I could integrate with mongodb to develop a powerful search framework ? How can I go about handling this issue ? What would be the best approach in this scenario ?

Comment: you need to create `text index` to get full text search support in mongodb

Comment: @ShaishabRoy  I have already created text index. What I need is a $regex search within a text search.

Comment: to perform text search no need to use `$regex` you should use `$text` and `$search`. can see my answer @oblivion

Answer (score 3):

To perform like full text search you can create `text index` and use then. [more about text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#create-text-index)

Syntax to create text index

```
db.colectionName.createIndex( { fieldName: "text" } );
```

Here shown for single field you can also create with multiple fields. but remember that

> A collection can have at most one text index.

then you can search using `$text` and  `$search`

```
var searchText= 'some text to search';
db.collectionName.find({ $text: { $search: searchText} });
```

But to *sequence matching or pattern matching* no need to create `text index` can use `$regex`.

```
var searchName ='som';
db.collectionName.find({"name":{ $regex: searchName, $options: 'i' }})
```

for above query with `$regex` that will match partially . for example in your db `name:'some text to search'` so can return data if `searchName` value  like `some`,`som`,`ome`, `rex` ...

for better performance can create normal index for `name` field

Comment: i need to perform like query with text search.
for eg: 
db.colectionName.createIndex( { fieldName: "text" } );                                                                                                                                
db.colectionName.insert( {"text":"some thing to search" } );                                                                                                                        
db.collectionName.find({ $text: { $search: "som"} });                      
As you can see, what I meant was I need something like $regex functionality with text search.

Comment: `$regex` is using for exact sequence matching or pattern matching not like `text search`

Comment: I know that, I am looking for partial text search where I could search using the substring of the actual text.

Comment: so what is the problem to use `text index` ?

Comment: you may miss understood about `text index` according to your first comment. you used `"text":"some thing to search"`to add new record that's not valid you should use `.insert( {"fieldName":"some thing to search"` and for that `fieldName` you should create `text index` and then use `.find({ $text: { $search: "som"} })` and that will find from `fieldName` values

Comment: yes, I made a typing mistake there. I meant `{"field_name":"some thing to search"`. But, do you think `.find({ $text: { $search: "som"} })` works in this case ? I think it will only match exact text or phrase.

Comment: @oblivion Did you find a solution for partial string matches?

Comment: @calbear47 no, i did not find any solution with MongoDB. I realized that I had to use search frameworks for advanced searching abilities. So, I decided to use ElasticSearch because it provides better support for nested json structures. I used `ElasticSearch` along with `MongoDB` with the help of `mongo-connector` between them. And it worked perfectly !!

Comment: @oblivion Cool, I'll check that project out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in SOLR but you need to define in advance the kinds of queries you will want to do and flatten the index in a creative ways so you can query and retrieve what you need. You can use multi-valued fields to store more than one value. You can store a JSON version of the entire object in a text field if your client needs to instantiate it.

For example you could store primaries and secondaries separately:

```
phone_number_primary: 1234,...
phone_number_secondary: 5678,...
my_json_blob: {OBJECT HERE}
```

then you can retrieve and query each separately. If you want to search for both you can either query both

```
 ( phone_number_primary:1234 OR phone_number_secondary:1234)
```

or you can define an extra field that stores both numbers in your schema:

```
 <copyField source="phone_number_*" dest="phone_number_all" />
```

and then search this field.